# jQuery open file dialog opens multiple times in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm making a website with Django to upload photos, following this [blog post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html). I've been developing in Firefox and it works fine. I just tried it in Chrome and Internet Explorer, and they both re-open the open file dialog after a file is selected. IE actually starts uploading after the first time (behind the re-opened dialog). Chrome doesn't start uploading until a second selection, and it will re-open the dialog if the first is closed or cancelled.

I've looked through related posts on SO, but I can't seem to find anything that makes sense to me. Why would the dialog open twice, given the code below? And why would it behave differently in Firefox?

*images_upload.html*:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <!-- {{ formE.as_p }} -->
</form>


  {% block javascript %}

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-file-upload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-file-upload/jquery.iframe-transport.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-file-upload/jquery.fileupload.js' %}"></script>

    <script src="{% static 'photos/js/images-upload.js' %}"></script>
  {% endblock %}

  {% block image_content %}
    <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-upload-photos">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Upload photos
      </button>
      <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="image" multiple
             style="display: none;"
             data-url="{% url 'ExifReader:image_upload' %}"
             data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
    </div>

    <div class="modal" id="modal-progress" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Uploading...</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="progress" style="height: 42px;">
              <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="height: 42px; width: 0%;">0%</div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <button id="done-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span>
              Done. View uploaded images.
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  {% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

*images-upload.js*:

```
$(function () {
  console.log('HERE'); // Added Sep. 13 for debugging - prints twice
  $(".js-upload-photos").click(function () {
    $("#fileupload").click();
  });

  $("#fileupload").fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    sequentialUploads: false,
    start: function (e) {
      $("#modal-progress").modal("show");
      $("#done-button").css("visibility","hidden");
    },
    stop: function (e) {
      $("#modal-progress").modal("show");
      $("#done-button").css("visibility","visible");
      $("#done-button").click(function() {
        window.location = '/imagerydatasystem/image_display'
      });
    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
      var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
      var strProgress = progress + "%";
      $(".progress-bar").css({"width": strProgress});
      $(".progress-bar").text(strProgress);
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
      if (data.result.is_valid) {
        $("#gallery tbody").prepend(
          "<tr><td><a href='" + data.result.url + "'>" + data.result.name + "</a></td></tr>"
        );
      }
    },
  });
});
```

Edit: I added the line `console.log('HERE');` on line 2 of `images-upload.js`, and in the console it's printed twice. I guess the script is getting called twice somehow?

Comment: I try to refer the example and find that in that example they had set sequentialUploads: false where as you had set it false. For testing purpose, try to set it true and check whether it fix the issue or not. If issue persist than you can try to debug your code step by step in IE or chrome which can help you to find which thing triggering the file upload multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried changing `sequentialUploads` from `false` to `true` but had the same result. Trying to debug line by line now, but having the extra level of Django is confusing me.

Comment: My guess would be that you are including images-upload.js multiple times on the page, or multiple jqueries, or both.  Look at your network tab when you hit the page.

Comment: The network tab confirms the script is included twice. Based on my understanding of Django, static files can be included multiple times without issues (e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999652/performance-hits-from-loading-django-static-tag-multiple-times)). Is this different? I added the full html template to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally tracked down the problem. In `base_generic.html` I had a javascript block:
    `{% block javascript %}{% endblock %}`
Even though there was nothing in that block, it apparently was looping the javascript block in `images_upload.html`. Solution: remove the block from `base_generic.html`.

Maybe this was obvious? Apparently I don't understand block tags that well.